# Send Email on Sql error in crontab centos

Tags: mysql, linux, email, cron

I have a MySql script that runs over cron tab in centos linux.

```
CALL some_stored_procedure();
```

there is a shell file which calls this MySql script with the name **callsqlscript.sh**

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword db_name < /home/scripts/SqlScrip.sql  >> /var/log/SqlscriptsLog.txt
```

here is my crontab entry

```
*/1 * * * * root /opt/scripts/callsqlscript.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "SQL Errors" something@mydomain.com
```

I am getting the emails every minute. I want email to be sent only if there any error running in SQL script.

Is there any way that I get the email only on errors. not every time

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use `1> /dev/null`

The message of the email is composed of the command's output. If there is none, no mail is sent.
The output is comprised of `stdout` and `stderr`

So by changing your command to

```
/opt/scripts/callsqlscript.sh 1> /dev/null
```

You redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` (normal output) while keeping `stderr` (the errors) active. If anything is produced in `stderr`, that will get emailed to your email address

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I am still getting the Emails with nothing inside.

Comment: **Null message body; hope that's ok**

I am getting this in the email